# Displaying last login time in php

Tags: php

I am beginner in Php. I have made a login and register system which works perfectly but I wish to display the last login time when the user logs in. I have a table(TIMESTAMP) which stores the data as 2013-03-08 00:00:00 . It displays the date but not the time. I also want to display these results when the user logs in.

I am using the below code when the data validation is successful and the user session variable is set.

```
$currentDate = date('Y-m-d g:i:s');
mysql_query('UPDATE `users` SET `last_sctivity` = "' . $currentDate . '"');
```

Comment: `g` in `g:i:s` uses 12 hour format and for SQL you need 24 hour format which is given by `h`, it should be `Y-m-d h:i:s`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can also use `now()` in the query if you not using `$currentDate` any where in the code

```
mysql_query('UPDATE `users` SET `last_sctivity` = now()');
```

also make sure the column `last_sctivity` is `timestamp` and not `date`

Comment: it is correct i suppose but i cant figure out why it is still showing the same 0000 format in the database and i have also used TIMESTAMP

Comment: Do not use mysql_*! It's deprecated and open to SQL injections. Use only mysqli_* or PDO with prepared statements!

`$time = date();
$stmt->$conn->query("UPDATE users SET last_activity = ?");
$stmt->bind_param("s", $time);
$stmt->execute();`

Comment: well times change in 7 years :) yes, please dont use mysql_query in 2020 .. how ever using `now()` in mysql query still makes sense.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this. I set my data-type of last_login to "timestamp"

```
$logintime = "UPDATE tbl_login SET last_login = now() where username = '$uname'";
mysqli_query($conn, $logintime);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try :

`$currentDate = date('Y-m-d h:i:s');`

Change `g:i:s` -> `h:i:s`

Answer (score 0):

Don't insert dates etc. using PHP functions in MySQL, when MySQL have appropriate functions for this. Use MySQL's `NOW()` instead.

Mixing PHP and MySQL when not needed is not recommended.

Comment: Thanks.. I have solved this. I have changed the datatype in mysql as int(11) and query as `mysql_query('UPDATE `users` SET `last_activity` = UNIX_TIMESTAMP()');`

However, this doesn't solve as whenever any user user logs in it updates the last_activity field.. How could I use this function to update the timestamp for each?

Answer (score 0):

```
$today = date('Y-m-d, g:i a');
$last = ("UPDATE users SET lastaccess = '$today'");
$query = mysqli_query($con, $last);
```

Comment: Generally including an explanation is desirable in an answer.